# How do i create an account to access the MS Graph API?

Tags: office365, office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I need to access the MS graph APIs to hit the basic APIs and to do so i need to create an account. I have already created an free business account through https://www.office.com/ 
But I do not have an access to the mail box, calendar, contacts.
Do i need to create a separate account? or is the objects available in the paid version?

Answer (score 1):

Chaitanya, if you already have an Office 365 account then you can use the Microsoft Graph API to get data in that account. You can start by accessing the basic set of requests using the Microsoft Graph API explorer: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer. The list of request you can try are in the overview documentation: https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/overview/overview. After that you can register your own app to get programmatic access to the data.

Comment: Is that possible to use Graph API with a regular MS account? I think I've seen something about that in an answer written by Dan Kershaw. I would like to fetch outlook.com calendar events.

Comment: Btw it's kind of impossible to contact Microsoft Graph team directly in any way, I spent two days looking for an email or so...

Comment: Yes, it is possible. To use the Microsoft Account for the Microsoft Graph, we need to use the v2 authentication endpoint. You can refer to [here](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/converged_auth).